# How to use string formatting in specific size based variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I know that when I use

```
"%2d"%(x)
```

I will get a string of x and in at least size of 2, and if the length of x is shorter than 2 I will get spaces before it.
But how can I give the 2 as a variable too?
For example:

```
"%nd"%(2,1)
' 1'
```

Is it possible in Python? Or do I need to create a loop for it?

Comment: `'%*d' % (n, x)` should work

Comment: @vaultah is right. It is working for me.

Comment: FWIW the new formatting should work in Python 2.7:  `'{:>{}}'.format(x, n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*` and the actual width will be read from the next element of the tuple of values, and the value to convert will be the one following:

```
>>> "%*d" % (2, 1)
' 1'
```

This is documented in the [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) section of the documentation — it says:

> 4. Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an `'*'` (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision.

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is what @vaultah commented an this works!

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to be more verbose with the *new style formatting*:

```
>>> '{:{width}d}'.format(1, width=2)
' 1'
```

Comment: @guy: Actually the new style is a bit more powerful (and easy, once you get the hang of it), so I suggest you take or make the time to learn it.